# Sub-classing or comprehensive class

Tags: c#, coding-style

I'm developing a distributed application (server and clients). There are some instructions sent by the server (e.g., `InitCommand`, `StartCommand`, `StopCommand`). Every command has its own arguments. Now if it's coming to serialization and networking, I'm asking myself whether I should create a sub-class for every command type (which inherits from `Command`) or just put all possible arguments in the `Command` class.

When handling a command it is `if (command is InitCommand)` vs `if (command.Type == CommandType.Init)`.

My first implementation uses the first option. I'm serializing by hand and put the type information at the beginning. Now if I receive data (`byte[]`) from network, I firstly check the actual type (deserialize only the first k bytes) and secondly use some deserialization methods (e.g., `Serializer.Deserialize<InitCommand>`).

The second option seems much easier to use, because I can use automated serialization and don't need to check the type before deserialization. But it annoys me, that I have to put all arguments into one class.

What do you think is better, or do you know about other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should have one class with multiple methods; `Start`, `Init`, `Stop`.  This would support everything in one class.  SqlCommand has a CommandType of `Text` `StoredProcedure`, and `TableDirect` and that sounds like what you're trying to rebuild for a different type of command.  I would choose #2 and look at how Microsoft Implemented [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) with `CommandType`.